# Changing order of for loops changes exponent product

Tags: python

What I am doing is creating a function that returns a list containing every number in a list of bases raised to every number in a list of powers. So, using a nested for loop I wrote two different ways:

First:

```
def exponents(bases, powers):
  lst = []
  for p in powers:
    for b in bases:
      lst.append(b ** p)
  return lst

print(exponents([2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]))
```

This prints:

```
[2, 3, 4, 4, 9, 16, 8, 27, 64]
```

These values are wrong.

Second:

```
def exponents(bases, powers):
  lst = []
  for b in bases:
  for p in powers:
    lst.append(b ** p)
  return lst

print(exponents([2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]))
```

This prints:

```
[2, 4, 8, 3, 9, 27, 4, 16, 64]
```

These are the correct values.

Why do these two very similar functions give different values? Is it related to floating point error?

Comment: Have you tried running through the loops by hand? It should become clear on your second iteration what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

Both functions are correct.  You changed the order in which you compute the results.
Rearrange the output to a tabular format:

```
[2, 3, 4,
 4, 9, 16,
 8, 27, 64]
```

vs

```
[2, 4, 8,
 3, 9, 27,
 4, 16, 64]
```

These are the same values, but with rows and columns switched ... just as you specified in your code when you switch the computation order.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example expands to:

```
2**1
3**1
4**1
2**2
3**2
4**2
2**3
3**3
4**3
```

Because for each `p`, loop through `b`

That computes to `[2, 3, 4, 4, 9, 16, 8, 27, 64]`

Your second example expands to:

```
2**1
2**2
2**3
3**1
3**2
3**3
4**1
4**2
4**3
```

Because you want for each `b`, loop through `p`
This computes to `[2, 4, 8, 3, 9, 27, 4, 16, 64]`

The values are correct--the order is different based on the order of looping that you desire